# JNI cleanup and daemon threads in Android NDK

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

So thats the flow of JNI

**JNI_onLoad** - get **JavaVM** (get jclass for calling static methods)

Then need to call something from Java to C:

**GetEnv()** to get **JNIEnv** and **AttachCurrentThread()** to use it.
Call java method
Process java method returned value.
**DetachCurrentThread()** - free thread
Somethere in the end
**DestroyJavaVM()**

Well questions are:

1. There to call DestroyJavaVM() and if i need to do so? In **onDestroy()** in my main Activity?
2. Is **JNI_onUnload** ever call and what i must clean up there?
3. Do i need somehow free **jclass** which i stored in static global vaiable?
4. Do JNI free local out of scope jarrays/jarrays elements, strings and string chars, jobjects after function return or i must always keep eye on that (calling **env->Release**(something))
5. What is benefits and usage of **AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon()**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. DestroyJavaVM() must be called when you no longer use the JVM (probably at the end of your program).
2. JNI_onUnload is called when the class is unloaded (because its class loader was deleted for example).
3. to free a Class null its references and delete its classloader.
4. JNI jarrays/jarrays elements, strings and jobjects are either allocated by the JVM or using a C buffer (that you manage); see #3 for the former case.
5. AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon() tells the JVM that it should not wait for the thread to exit upon shutdown (helpful for daemons).

Good luck!

Comment: What is the logic behind a -1 for questions that are 3 years old and "accepted" as a relevant answer for their author?

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but I can see why some might quibble with it. The question was Android-specific, but Android has historically not supported class unloading, and there's not much value in destroying the VM. Freeing a `jclass` reference isn't the same as freeing a class, e.g. if you were doing it in a loop you'd want to free the local ref. Some native arrays *must* be explicitly released, e.g. after `Get*ArrayElements`, but #4 doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Nobody had answered the question so punishing the only (and accepted!) answer 3 years later is a very good incentive to discourage people from contributing with their "best knowledge". Food for thoughts?